# Simplest way to create new users in Tableau Server programmatically? (C#)

Tags: c#, tableau-api

I have a web simple form that validates users against AD. The Tableau Server is configured to use AD and I'd like to use the Tableau REST API to add users with the 'interactor' role to Tableau Server. Is there a simple way to do this in C# .NET? Here's the codebehind:

```
private bool IsValidActiveDirectoryUser(string activeDirectoryServerDomain, string username, string password)
{
    try
    {
        DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + activeDirectoryServerDomain, username + "@" + activeDirectoryServerDomain, password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
        DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);
        ds.FindOne();
        //user is validated so extract AD username and send to Tableau
    }
    catch //(Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I know acccording to http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_ref.htm I want to do something like

```
tabcmd createuser ADname --license "interactor"
```

But how can I do this in C#? Problems I'm running into include exatract the correct credentials and how to send it to Tableau Server.

Comment: Lots of examples here https://github.com/tableau. Take a look at the Python server library that simplifies using the REST API. If you can't switch to Python, maybe you could start a C# version of that library.

Comment: If you are programmatically using the REST API, your code talks directly to the web server over HTTP. You don't use tabcmd in that case.

Answer (score 0):

When using AD authentication in Tableau you shouldn't create users by hand. There is a mechanism for this: 
https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/groups_globalsync.htm

It even allows you to set role for new accounts.